# Synonym of the word "tautologie"

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, synonymes

Is there any one-word synonym of the word "tautologie" (which mean repeat a self-evident proposition)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A tautology is a proposition that is always true (self-evident if you will). The wiktionary example is nifty:

> 100% de nos clients achètent nos produits.

The word you're looking for is maybe *pléonasme*: a redundant use of words. Typically:

> Je l'ai vu de mes propres yeux.
>
> Monte en haut.

If an already self-evident proposition is redundantly worded then maybe you could call it a *tautologie pléonastique*, but that's two words, and in that case you'd better add a specific example in your question.

Comment: *tautologie pléonastique* est un abus d'excès caractérisé par trop d'exagération, non ? N'est-ce pas lui-même un pléonasme ?

Answer (score 8):

Redondance, répétition, pléonasme, truisme sont tous des synonymes de Tautologie.
J'aime beaucoup le mot truisme comme une alternative au mot tautologie.
Ma préférence allant au mot: "lapalissade". 
Lapalissade étant un synonyme de tautologie en énonçant une évidence connue de tous mais apportant une nuance cynique et ironique que n'a pas nécessairement la tautologie.

Comment: Pas d'accord pour l'assimilation de "lapalisade" avec "tautologie" ! On a bien dit du seigneur de La Palice, Maréchal de France, qu'un quart d'heure avant sa mort il était encore en vie. Mais c'est oublier que "bien vivant" signifiait à l'époque "très actif", on dirait maintenant "il a été brave, vaillant, jusqu'à la dernière extrémité".